# On "git push web" error: unable to resolve reference refs/remotes/web/ui: No error

Tags: git, github, git-push

I have two GIT branches,

1) development

2) ui

Where development branch i have cloned to local and make changes in it, then follow the below steps to upload all the changes to branches.

**Below are the steps of commands i used to run:**

1) git status

2) git checkout development // name of development branch

3) git add

4) git commit

5) git push // pushing development changes on development branch only

6) git checkout ui // name of ui branch

7) git merge development

8) git push web ui // pushing changes on ui branch

All the above commands works perfectly except 8th ( git push web ui ). When i run this command on git bash its give me below messages.

```
$ git push web ui
Counting objects: 30, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Writing objects: 100% (16/16), 3.19 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 16 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Already on 'ui'
remote: ----------------------------------------------------------------
remote: Deployed ui to Leo
remote: ----------------------------------------------------------------
To ssh://git@account.com/srv/git/acc.git
   e258b99..8563f31  ui -> ui
error: unable to resolve reference refs/remotes/web/ui: No error
error: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/remotes/web/ui'.
```

But all the changes are successfully updated on both branches, i can check on git server as well as web site too.

So why this error message displaying at the end of push on web?

> error: unable to resolve reference refs/remotes/web/ui: No error
>   error: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/remotes/web/ui'

Anyone's help for resolve this error will really appreciated!

Comment: Try to do the step 8 with the `--verbose` option and post the console output there.

Comment: and a `git remote -v`

Comment: Looks to me like a failure in one of the hook scripts, not in `git` itself... Above suggestions for verbose execution would be the best place to start...